# According to mainstream Christianity, who is God?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity

> This question also relates to it:
>   [What is the Biblical basis for the doctrine of the Trinity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/72/biblical-basis-for-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity)

Growing up I've been led to believe that God is God, and Jesus is God's son. But others have also preached that Jesus was God, in a human's body.

And nearly everywhere I go online these days, I end up seeing some website that claims that Jesus *is* God.

So which is it? Are God and Jesus the same being? Is Jesus God's son? There are some Christian websites that claim different things, so I am confused.

What do the majority of Christians say about this topic?

Comment: P.S.  There are many copies of the bible online - I'd suggest biblegateway.com or bible.org.  Barring that, send me an email, and I'll mail you one myself!

Comment: And Welcome to Christianity.SE!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE.  Please see the answers to the questions noted as this particular issue has already been dealt with.

Comment: @Jase Why did you have a "Catholicism" tag on this question? If you are a Catholic or want an answer from a Catholic perspective, then we should not have closed this question or edited it like we did. Let us know, and welcome to the site.

Comment: @Alypius, Hi :) I included Catholicism as a tag because I am a little confused about which I should be following.

Comment: @Jase All mainstream Christians and that includes Catholics have same view on Jesus as God so also on Holy Trinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are having difficulty grokking is a concept known as the "Trinity."  The historically correct definition of the Trinity is that God is "three persons in one."

When Jesus says, "I and the Father are One" (in John), he is claiming that he is God.  Historically, God the Father, Jesus (God the Son), and the Holy Spirit are all considered the three persons of the Trinity.  They are all equal, they are distinct, and yet they are all the same.

This [link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/13655/1039) explains the relationship as well as any :)

Don't worry, its a difficult concept, but it is the basis of Nicene Christianity's understanding of how God exists.

Comment: If it answered your question, clicking the green check mark to "accept" my answer would appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @AffableGeek, looks like I have a lot more reading to do. If only they had video cameras back then, it would be so much easier lol.