# If Jesus ascended to heaven as Michael the angel why is he still called a man?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, jehovahs-witnesses, 1-timothy, michael

Jehovah's Witnesses believe Jesus was resurrected as a spirit creature Michael the archangel. If this is so, why do they still call him a man?

**[1 Timothy 2:5 (King James Version)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+tim+2%3A5&version=KJV)**:

> For there is one God, and one mediator between God and men, the man Christ Jesus;

Comment: Hey Tony, Incidentally, Jehovah Witnesses are Arians when it comes to their understanding of the relationship between the Son and the Father (but not Arian in any other sense; Arians could arguably be considered "more orthodox" than than JW).

Comment: BTW this is a better verse to argue that the Son and the Father are unequal.

Comment: No it is not. JWs get into category errors by assuming there cannot be more than one person in the one God. Hence every verse which clearly shows Jesus is more than just a creature is a problem.

Comment: In your question [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26533/how-do-trinitarians-interprete-john-526), you use the verse "For as the Father has life in himself, so he has granted the Son also to have life in himself." This can be interpreted as the Son lives in the Father; i.e., they are coequal. The verse in this question, "For there is one God, and one mediator between God and men, the man Christ Jesus;" can be interpreted as Christ being separate from God, as he is the "one mediator between God and men".

Comment: Would you explain in more detail regarding "JWs get into category errors by assuming there cannot be more than one person in the one God. Hence every verse which clearly shows Jesus is more than just a creature is a problem" ?

Answer (score 1):

His role on this earth was as a man, and he may properly be referred to in this way.

**1 Corinthians 15:45-47**

> So it is written: "The first man Adam became a living person." The last Adam became a life-giving spirit. However, what is spiritual is not first. What is physical is first, and afterward what is spiritual.  The first man is from the earth and made of dust; **the second man is from heaven.**

Thus, Jesus is both "a life-giving spirit" and "the second man".