# Our prayers should be aimed at who?

Tags: prayer

I know that Jesus died for my sins, and I know that we pray in Jesus' name, but should we ask Jesus or God the Father?

Comment: This is an academic site and does not give personal advice. The question you are asking is not (in my own view or experience) the sort of enquiry that suits asking impersonally of strangers on the internet but would better be asked in a more personal context. The official wording of the site is as follows : _Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor._

Comment: Please read [What types of questions can I ask on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/6071)

Comment: I have edited your question to make it acceptable to the site (I believe) while keeping the same intention. If this wasn't your intention then please revert the edits.

Comment: @DJClayworth It's better to wait for the author to initiate such an edit. In this case the author appears to be a firm non-Trinitarian, so I've rolled back your edit until they can clarify.

Comment: I will not reopen the question, as I have already reached the conclusion and understood what this site is about, as this is not the place for sincere questions and to awaken people to judgment and sense.

As read in the note, this is not a place for Christians, as I thought. But anyway, no more words (sorry for the sincerity)

PLEASE NOTE: despite the name, this is a secular site. We cannot answer your religious questions personally. (https://christianity.stackexchange.com/contact --> https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/brothers-we-are-not-christians)

Answer (score 1):

The most definitive answer comes from Matthew 6:9

> This, then, is how you should pray:
>
> “‘**Our Father** in heaven,
> hallowed be your name,

But in prayer words are for you, not for him. Matthew 6:8 says:

> Do not be like them, for your Father knows what you need before you ask him.

Jesus and God the Father are aspects of the same - at the end of the day it matters little which you pray to. If Jesus' name comes more easily to you then don't feel you must 'correct' yourself.

Comment: 'Aspects of the same' implies monotheism. Is that what you meant to say ?

Comment: @NigelJ *Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is one* - Deut 6:4 and *Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit* - Mat 28:19. The nature of God is both one and three at the same time.

Comment: "_The nature of God is both one and three at the same time._" still implies monotheism. Only the precise confession of three individual Persons clearly states the Trinitarian, Nicene, position.

Comment: @NigelJ I see you have a particular interpretation - and you're welcome to that - but there are [others](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12637/what-is-the-doctrine-of-the-trinity) that believe [otherwise](https://www.equip.org/article/understanding-nicene-trinitarianism/). This isn't the place for that debate.

Comment: I would've said that "aspects of the same" sounds dangerously like modalism. You may not have meant that, but it's poor phrasing for a Trinitarian position.

Comment: @curiousdannii Is my use of the term 'monotheism' incorrect ? I notice you say 'modalism' which is perhaps more accurate than my own word, in this context.

Comment: @NigelJ All Trinitarians are monotheists. I'm not sure if that's what you meant, or if you meant modalism, where there is only one divine person who acts and appears as the father, son, and spirit at various times.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, that is what I meant. I need to use your word 'modalism' in future, for clarity. Thank you.