# "Jesus Christ, son of God" or "Jesus Christ is God"?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, names-of-god

If Jesus Christ is God, why are there passages stating that Jesus is the son of God?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  When you have a chance, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web.  As worded, this question is extremely broad (different questions will answer differently) and thus not answerable within site guidelines.  To be on-topic, you would have to ask how a specific denomination/group of Christians answer the question.

Comment: That said, [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/why-do-christians-call-jesus-the-son-of-god-rather-than-simply-god) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: There is no reason that Jesus cannot be both, we know from the bible Jesus is the son of God (Mark 14:61-62, John 1:49) but Jesus is also called God (John 20:28, 2 Peter 1:1, Titus 2:13) it isn't either or, Christ can be both the son of men and God, God is all knowing and all powerful and can anything.