# What is the earliest clear and unambiguous post-NT denial of the Holy Spirit's personhood in Christianity?

Tags: church-history, nature-of-god, pneumatology, non-trinitarian

Essentially the opposite of [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/82780/50422):

1. What is the earliest recorded post-NT instance of a clear and unambiguous **denial** of the personhood of the Holy Spirit? When was it claimed for the first time that the Holy Spirit is *not* a Person, distinct from the Father and the Son, in the history of Christianity?
2. When did this belief reach widespread acceptance among Christians for the first time, if ever?

Comment: Servetus (~1530) denied the personhood of the Holy Spirit. "He contends that
the Bible designates the Holy Spirit only as God’s “activity,” i.e., the power of God, and
thus not a person." http://servetustheevangelical.com/doc/ServetusFromBook.pdf Going back more than a thousand years before that, various writers talked as if the HS was not a 'person', but I don't know if there were explicit denials of this still in writing. Rather, they would be inferences from the way they talk about it.

Comment: "When did this belief reach widespread acceptance among Christians for the first time" This seems to be the standard belief from the beginning. Instead, the doctrine of '3 persons in one God' with the HS as one of those 'persons' was the new idea.

Comment: "No theologian in the first three Christian centuries was a trinitarian in the sense of a believing that the one God is tripersonal, containing equally divine “persons”, Father, Son, and Holy Spirit." https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/trinity/trinity-history.html

Comment: I take it here you are asking for a denial of 'personhood', not equal personhood?

Comment: Another question would be what 'person' means, and what the denial of 'personhood' might mean. Consider "Augustine suggests that the standard creedal term “person” (Greek: hypostasis or prosopon; Latin: persona) **is adopted simply so that something may be said in answer to the question “What is God three of?”** (224–30 [VII.3], 241 [VIII.1.1], 398 [XV.1.5]) The term “person”, he thinks, signifies a genus, but it is one for which we can provide no species." (ibid.) Heh.

Comment: My guess is any such explicit denial would have to be a response to Tertullian (or later writers), who appears to have pioneered the use of 'persons' to describe God, so after ~208.

Comment: @OneGodtheFather: `I take it here you are asking for a denial of 'personhood', not equal personhood?` - Yes, that's what I mean. Denial of personhood regardless of whether equality is affirmed or denied.